# How To Setup Custom Permission Level in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have 7 SharePoint Lists, with a Role: Operation Manager, Operation Teams, Admin

I've created permission levels for each list with the following conditions. I created a SharePoint group on these permissions.

[image]

[image]

But when I share that list (based on the conditions in the image).
[image]

[image]
Is there something wrong with this my way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose a permission level,not a group.
[image]

You must select a permission level instead of a group for this option.
Similiar issue for your reference:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2338078-3418-467f-81f0-e0ee2b332b3e/cant-grant-permission-for-groups-to-access-site?forum=sharepointadminprevious